# How to Remove Remote FTP Folders older than 3 days in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I need to remove folders in a ftp storage which are older than 3 days. I mean the creation date, not the modification date. I should do it only by PHP FTP Commands. Here is my code which don't work properly:

```
$skip = array('.', '..', '.ftpquota', '.htaccess');
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days', time()));
$ff_list = ftp_nlist($con, $db_dir);
foreach($ff_list as $item)
{
    if(in_array($item, $skip))
    {
        continue;
    }
    $mod_time = ftp_mdtm($con, $item);
    if(strtotime($expire_date ) >= $mod_time)
    {
        ftp_rmdir($con, $item);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to make it okay...

Comment: Well, what is happening, what is going wrong? What is `expire_date` showing?

Comment: What's the difference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224502/remove-old-remote-ftp-folders ?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is using DirectoryIterator

```
<?php
if (file_exists($folderName)) {
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folderName) as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
        continue;
        }
        if ($fileInfo->isFile() && time() - $fileInfo->getCTime() >= 3*24*60*60) {
            unlink($fileInfo->getRealPath());
        }
    }
}
?>
```